# UnicodeDecodeError when passing GET data in Python/AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

This feels like a really basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I would like to read data from an url, for example GET data from a querystring. I am using the `webapp` framework in Python. I tried the following code, but since I've a total beginner at Python/appengine, I've certainly done something wrong.

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(self.request.get('data'))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),('/search', Search),('/next', Next)],debug=False)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When testing in my test environment, the URL `http://localhost/?data=test` just returns this error message below. Without the querystring, it just displays a blank page as expected.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do instead?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Where is the error coming from? Could you include the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, it seems like the real issue wasn't the code getting the GET-data, but something else. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to e.g. print an ASCII coded string actually containing data of a different charset. This can happen e.g. with Latin-1 encoded data. Try converting your input to unicode using

```
unicoded = unicode(non_unicode_string, source_encoding)
```

where `source_encoding` is something like `'cp1252'`, `'iso-8859-1'` etc., and sending this to output.

Have a look at [this HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html). For a list of encodings supported by Python, see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: Thanks! This error occurred when trying to write the result from a urlfetch query. What I cannot understand thought, is why the error just occured when I tried to pass a querystring to it, not when I didn't?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python) on how to do unicode right in Python. In a nutshell, you're trying to decode a byte string (implicitly) as ASCII, and it contains a byte that isn't valid in that codec. Your string is probably in UTF-8.

Comment: A Unicode string [snip] contains a character that can't be represented as unicode??????

Comment: -1 If the OP was trying to encode a Unicode string as ASCII, and it didn't "fit", he would get a Unicode **En** codeError -- the OP reports Unicode **De** codeError.

Comment: @John You're right - fixed. Voting down for a simple typo seems a bit unwarranted, though.

Comment: (1) The -1 was for reading the question bassackwards: "encode" instead of "decode" (2) "unicode" instead of "ascii" is a simple typo??

Comment: @John It's fixed now - so feel free to remove your downvote. Unless you believe the updated answer is still inaccurate?