# What caused this traceback?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UnicodeDecodeError when passing GET data in Python/AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570434/unicodedecodeerror-when-passing-get-data-in-python-appengine)

I get the following traceback locally and on production when trying to submit a form. Can you explain where I should look or should I start making debugging statements to see where in the code the exception occurs?

```
 -->  --> -->

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3858, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3792, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 580, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2918, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2822, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2704, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    script_module.main()
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/classifiedsmarket/main.py", line 2497, in main
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 116, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 655, in __call__
    response.wsgi_write(start_response)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 274, in wsgi_write
    body = self.out.getvalue()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/StringIO.py", line 270, in getvalue
    self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: -1 for not reading the error message: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)` There's something wrong with your input data, or at least it seems so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570434/unicodedecodeerror-when-passing-get-data-in-python-appengine

Answer (score 5):

The error manifested itself in /usr/lib/python2.6/StringIO.py i.e. the Python StringIO module. We don't need to read too far into that source file (line 49) to find this warning:

> ```
> The StringIO object can accept either Unicode or 8-bit strings, but
> mixing the two may take some care. If both are used, 8-bit strings that
> cannot be interpreted as 7-bit ASCII (that use the 8th bit) will
> cause a UnicodeError to be raised when getvalue() is called.
> ```

Bingo! And the warning is repeated again in the getvalue() method. Note that the warning is ancient; it mentions UnicodeError instead of UnicodeDecodeError, but you get the drift.

I'd suggest patching the module so that it displays what's in the bag when the error happens. Wrap up the offending statement at line 270 like this:

```
if self.buflist:
    try:
        self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        import sys
        print >> sys.stderr, "*** error context: buf=%r buflist=%r" % (self.buf, self.buflist)
        raise
    self.buflist = []
return self.buf
```

If the idea of patching a Python-supplied module in situ horrifies you, put the patched version in a directory that's earlier in `sys.path` than `/usr/lib/python2.6`.

Here's an example of mixing non-ASCII `str` and `unicode`:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> f.write('ascii')
>>> f.write(u'\u1234'.encode('utf8'))
>>> f.write(u'\u5678')
>>> f.getvalue()
*** error context: buf='' buflist=['ascii', '\xe1\x88\xb4', u'\u5678']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python26\lib\StringIO.py", line 271, in getvalue
    self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Then you can run your application and look at what is in `buflist`: which parts are data that you wrote, and which are provided by GAE. You need to look at the GAE docs to see whether it is expecting `str` contents (with what encoding?) or `unicode` contents, and adjust your code accordingly.